# Javascript: Passing objects by reference

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference, javascript-objects

In my applications I am not sure if I am duplicating data when I pass it around to different objects.  Just as an example have a look at the following code:

```
var DataStore = function(data) {
    this.data = data; // <-- typeof data === 'object'
}

var Controller = function() {
    var dataStore = new DataStore({foo: 'bar'});
    var plugin = new Plugin(dataStore.data);
}

var Plugin = function(data) {
   this.data = data;
}

var app = new Controller();
```

When I create Plugin it is passed the data property from dataStore.  It is then assigned to a property inside Plugin.  Keeping in mind that the data being passed around is an object my question is, is this creating two variables in memory or does the data property in Plugin reference the property in the DataStore object?

If it doesn't keep the reference after assignment, how can I pass the DataStore into Plugins and keep a reference to it locally?  Or would I need to keep DataStore as a global variable in my application scope and reference it globally from the plugins?

Comment: AFAIK JavaScript objects are always references

Comment: @AlvinWong Not quite. Objects in ECMAScript implementations like JavaScript can only be *accessed through* a reference, and object references are *values* (which can be assigned). Call-by-reference as known from other programming languages *does not exist*, it is *always* call-by-value. This is the same as, e.g., in Java.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both `dataStore.data` and `plugin.data` reference the same object - mutating the object in either of these "classes" (for lack of a better term) will result in the object being mutated for both of them (since they are both holding references to the same object).

Comment: This is correct and probably the practical piece of information future googlers want.  While the other answers/comments here list the technical reasons why javascript is not actually "call-by-reference", it still behaves very similarly from a programmer's perspective when dealing with object parameters.  Additionally, I'll also add, that if you do NOT wish for this behavior, you would need to do something like the following (using jQuery, but every library will have it's own implementation) `var copy = $.extend(true, {}, data);` and then pass `copy` instead of `data`

Answer (score 0):

Function arguments are always passed by reference in JS. When you pass an object as an argument, what gets passed is actually a *pointer* to the object's location in memory. If you attempt to overwrite the reference itself, nothing will happen to the original object, however if you change the value of any of the object's properties, the original object will be modified.

Ex:

```
function f1(_x) {
    _x = 5;
}

function f2(_y) {
    _y.name = 'Hello';
}

var x = 10;
f1(x);
console.log(x); // no change to x

var y = {name: 'Tom'};
f2(y);
console.log(y.name); // y.name is now Hello
```

Comment: No, there is no "pass-by-reference in JS", and function arguments are not different from other values. There are no pointers at the language level (there may be at implementation level, but that is not specified). The reference is not overwritten, the parameter value is, and the parameter is local to the function.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: @SeainMalkin You accepted a wrong answer. Do you understand that only the reference value is copied (call-by-value), and not the object?

Comment: @PointedEars - I know there is no feature called pointers in JS, but you do get the point that what is passed is a handle to the object in memory and the object itself. Right? Also, i used the terms pointer, reference etc.. only to make the answer clear. And by overwriting the reference, what i meant was overwriting the value of the argument (which may happen to be a reference to another object)

Comment: @techfoobar Whether pointers are used on the implementation level depends on the lower-level language of the ECMAScript implementation (e.g. C++ for SpiderMonkey) and is well beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: @techfoobar  "Call-by-reference" or, as you put it, "pass-by-reference" has a specific meaning in programming. It is simply *wrong* to say that "function arguments are passed by reference" (in JS), as if they were special in some way, because they are not. What is assigned, and what is passed, is a *reference value*, and it is passed to the function as such (call-by-value). See also ["Functions and function scope" at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope).

Comment: @techfoobar Correction: SpiderMonkey is written in C.

Comment: +1 for the links and info. I do realize that my choice of terms could have been better. I was only trying to explain it in a way i thought was easiest to understand.

Comment: @PointedEars His terminology may not have been perfect but it got the point across and the example proved what I wanted to know.